# Passing variable with properties to argumentlist, loosing properties

Tags: powershell, arguments, start-job

```
$Computers = Get-QADComputer -sizelimit 5
```

returns a list of five computers. I loop with

```
foreach($computer in $computers) {
echo "and then I can do this $computer.name"
```

to get only the computername from $computers.
But When i try to pass it to start-job like this:

```
    Start-Job -FilePath $ScriptFile -Name $Computer.Name -ArgumentList $Computer
```

I am unable to do a $computer.name inside $scriptfile. I have to pass it like $computer.name and call it like $args[0]. But then I loose all the other properties (I am using a bunch inside $scriptfile.)

What am I not getting here? What would you call $computer? And what would you call $computer.name ?

Sune:)

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get the Name property with $args[0].Name. If you want to access the name parameter like so: $computer.name, then you need to define a parameter in $ScriptFile:

```
param(
   $Computer
)

$Computer.name
```

By the way' you can't do this:

```
echo "and then I can do this $computer.name"
```

PowerShell expands the value $computer only. Put it in a sub-expression:

```
echo "and then I can do this $($computer.name)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly so, this is how I would write something similar:

```
#Get Services
$Services = Get-Service
#Limit results to the first 5 entries
$Services = $Services[0..4]
#Loop through services
foreach ($Service in $Services)
{
    #For each Service run a basic echo to host to prove that the Service was passed in successfully
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param ($Service) Write-Host "Service Name is $($Service.Name)" } -ArgumentList $Service
}
```

You can then retrieve the Jobs like this:

```
#Retrieve Jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```